# How to know the co-ordinates of selected marker on Google Map

Tags: objective-c, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

I want to plot a polyline on google map for selected marker. I have around 20 markers pinned on Google map. The markers are plotted on the basis of data returned by Google Places API. I store all the co-ordinates in an array and then use reverse geo-coding to get address for that particular coordinates.

Then to use marker, I called the delegate method didTapMarker and inside that I am hitting the Google Directions API.

But my problem is:- User can select any marker irrespective of indexPath value of array in which the co-ordinates are stored. So how to draw poly line for randomly selected marker on Google Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well somehow I did it.

All I need is to use userData property of GMSMarker.
I assigned each marker a markerID inside "**for loop**" like this:

```
marker.userData = @{@"marker_id":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]};
```

then under didTapMarker delegate of GMSMapView, I called the Google Directions API like this

```
   NSDictionary *tempDic=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
   tempDic=marker.userData;
   int value= [tempDic[@"marker_id"]intValue];

  NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&alternatives=true&origin=%@&destination=%@&key=%@&sensor=false",addressAt,[tempArray objectAtIndex:value],googleAPI_Key];
  //addressAt is the current location of user i.e source and for destination I called the array in which my converted address is stored
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the marker which was tapped.
Use the following property to get its location on map.

```
marker.position
```

Comment: Not of much help , it returns nothing.